# What does the kilogram-hertz relationship stand for?

Tags: waves, physical-constants

The value of the **kilogram-hertz relationship** [$(1kg)c^2/h]$ physics constant is 1.356 392 608 $\times 10^{50}\,\mathrm{Hz}$.

What does this constant stand for?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics SE. Look around at the questions, and please take the Tour. In its current form, I find you question unclear - what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: If we say that the gravitational constant stands for the force of attraction between two bodies, what does the kilogram-hertz relationship involve in physical terms? The answer given seem to explain that relationship. Is it exact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having never actually used this formally as a constant, I don't know the utility of it, but I can tell from the definition where it comes from.

$E=mc^2$ is the energy associated/belonging to a mass, $m$. $E=hf$ tells us the relationship between the energy of a photon associated with an EM wave of frequency $f$.

The **kilogram-hertz** relationship would be the frequency of a photon which has the same energy as a mass of 1 kg in its rest frame.

It may have utility in the upcoming *redefinition of the  kilogram* by the General Conference on Weights and Measures [discussed here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_redefinition_of_SI_base_units) You can also find more at the site of [National Institute of Science and Technologies.](http://www.nist.gov/pml/si-redef/kg_redefinition.cfm)